# How to get distance between two points Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Here is a query:

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSpheroid(geometry(a.location), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(28.828042, 47.023565)', 4326), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
FROM users a
WHERE a.id=1
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(28.828042, 4" <-- parse error at position 18 within geometry


SQL state: XX000
```

Where did I make mistake??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-known Text representations of points don't need a comma. Try this:

`POINT(28.828042 47.023565)`

Comment: Now I got this: ERROR:  geometry_distance_spheroid: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Point, 0) != (Point, 4326)

Comment: This works for me: `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(28.828042 47.023565)')`

Comment: Ad result I got meters?

Comment: The results are in metres, yes. See the docs: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html